# best way to tell user a notification like 'sucess' or 'error' in mvc

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, notifications

hallo im trying to do something like

```
$this->model->users->updateData ( $e );
$this->messenger->setMessage('Updated');
# tells that hello user the data is updated!
redirect ( '/edit/profile' );
# trying to update the data, the main problem when redirect all the data is gone
```

heres are the options

1. use sessions to put the message in then deletes if its showed
2. use ?updated on urls get it with a is_get or something like that
3. use ajax to update the new data on the edit/profile

or there is a better way on doing this ?

Comment: What mvc framework are you using?

Comment: All three options are feasible and are known to be implemented in the wild.

Comment: Option 1 is often called Flash Messages in case you want to search for existing classes available out there.

Answer (score 0):

The Flash Messenger Helper may be what you are looking for.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

Comment: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-frameworks-flash-messenger-action-helper/ a good writeup on it's uses